# I stand with or I'm standing with

Tags: phrases

Ok, this might be dim, but Google failed me (or I him).

So, we're talking about a phrase "I stand with X". As in being on the same side, together against something, etc.

A certain someone is trying to convince me that "I am standing with X" is just as good of an option. But it sounds wrong. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Technically,
"I stand with him." is **a general idea.** "Whenever he complains about the service from this company". You could not use the ing form here.

WHEREAS:

"I'm standing with him on this issue until further notice". is **a specific idea.** Like all uses of the continuous, it points to the present time.

Ergo, the way we use the present simple versus the present progressive applies here. It's always about **context**.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. 
So, say "I am so-and-so and I  stand with Japan".

Comment: The -ing form would be rare in an idiom like "I stand with," which is usually used to express resolve. To use the -ing form to indicate temporariness, i.e. to say you're "standing with" someone until further notice, kind of defeats the point.

Comment: @cruthers My explanation is correct. "I stand with expresses resolve" does not include  a temporary situation, and it is perfectly reasonable to suppose some situations are temporary.

Comment: I'm not really saying you're incorrect. I'm saying that the answer would benefit from a little more in the way of expressing how comparatively rare -ing would be, given the typical use of the idiom. Even your given example is hard to imagine in real life.

Comment: I don't think 'I'm standing with xxx' is all that rare. I stand with the Labour Party on issues such as equality and public services. I am standing with Councillor Mukerjee in her current effort to improve our area's road safety awareness.

Comment: Thank you, Michael.